# Организация логики ООП в приложении, работающем на парсинге

Tags: java, android, инспекция-кода

Делаю клиент для онлайн игрушки, у неё нет публичного API и пришлось делать все на парсинге. Я организовал пакет `api` с пакетами `request` (интерфейсы сетевых запросов) и `propeller` (захотелось так назвать, тут происходит парсинг DOM). Я создал базовый пропеллер

```
public abstract class BasePropeller
{
public abstract void turn(Document doc);
}
```

И теперь могу от него наследовать все классы для парсинга. К примеру, вот класс для парсинга профиля.

```
public class ProfilePropeller extends BasePropeller
{
public String nick;

@Override
public void turn(Document doc)
{
    nick = /* парсим ник игрока */
}
}
```

Интерфейс а-ля сетевой запрос

```
public interface ProfileRequest
{
void success (ProfilePropeller profile);
void error (String error);
}
```

Также я создал класс `Api` с методами, принимающими параметры и выполняющими запрос

```
public static void getProfile(long id, final ProfileRequest request)
{
    Grabber.grab(Constants.URL.PROFILE + id).wait(new Waiter(){
            @Override
            public void success(Document doc)
            {
                ProfilePropeller profile = new ProfilePropeller();
                profile.turn(doc);
                request.success(profile);
            }

            @Override
            public void error(String msg)
            {
                request.error(msg);
            }
        });
}
```

`Grabber` и `Waiter` это классы из моего модуля для асинхронного получения HTML верстки.

Скажите, хорошо ли получается? Что тут нужно изменить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По хорошему у ProfilePropeller должна быть одна обязанность: распарсить документ, отдать (в лучшем случае неизменяемый) объект профиля. Смысла в BasePropeller я не вижу, если он введен для отказа от дублирования кода, то лучше добавить его полем в ProfilePropeller. 
ну и я бы переименовал ProfilePropeller в ProfileParser, а BasePropeller в Propeller.

к примеру:

```
public class ProfileParser
{
    private Propeller propeller;

    ProfileParser() {
        propeller = new Propeller();
    }

    public Profile parse(Document doc) {
        String nick = propeller.parse("name", doc);
        return new Profile(nick);
    }
}
```

тогда далее

```
public static void getProfile(long id, final ProfileRequest request)
{
    Grabber.grab(Constants.URL.PROFILE + id).wait(new Waiter(){
        @Override
        public void success(Document doc)
        {
            ProfileParser profileParser= new ProfileParser();
            request.success(profileParser.parse(doc));
        }

        @Override
        public void error(String msg)
        {
            request.error(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Я отказался от модели, потому что слишком много данных в профиле.

Comment: когда слишком много данных, я бы не отказывался от модели, а добавлял новые, чтобы инкапсулировать эти данные

Comment: Тоесть например, подклассы в модели? К примеру, есть ник, уровень, кубки, опыт - это все можно поместить в `UserInfo`, его клан, опыт, внесенные ресурсы в бюджет клана - в `ClanInfo`, его статус, онлайн и подарки - `SocialInfo`. Я правильно понял?

Comment: ресурсы внесенные в бюджет клана я бы хранил в сущности клана, например в объекте с полями ключ пользователя, сумма денег, дата. мне кажется более логичным что эта инфа принадлежит клану. А в целом можно и так, только я стараюсь избегать наследования. Рекомендую почитать о принципах SOLID, книги вроде "Рефакторинг" Мартина Фаулера и "Совершенный код" Макконела, Боба мартина, тогда все станет на свои места.

Comment: Во, точно, большое спасибо за книги